# Compiler Segmantion fault durint ROS installation on OSX Lion

Tags: rosinstall, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I know that Osx is only "experimental" supported and that Lion is really new.

Despite that, I'm trying to install ROS on my machine.
I'm following the guide on [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/OSX) but I had a segmentation fault error.

The output is the following:

```
Bootstrapping ROS build
Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too.
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ros', 'ros_comm']                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/Users/luca/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110722-113953                                                         
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ros', 'ros_comm'] to:
['rosunit', 'rospack', 'rosmake', 'rosemacs', 'rosdep', 'roscreate', 'rosclean', 'rosboost_cfg', 'rosbash', 'test_rospack', 'test_rosmake', 'test_roslib', 'test_rosdep', 'test_roscreate', 'roslib', 'roslang', 'rosbuild', 'mk', 'xmlrpcpp', 'roswtf', 'rostime', 'message_filters', 'cpp_common', 'topic_tools', 'rostopic', 'rostest', 'rosservice', 'rosrecord', 'rosparam', 'rosout', 'rosnode', 'rosmsg', 'rosmaster', 'roslaunch', 'rosgraph', 'rosconsole', 'rosbagmigration', 'rosbag', 'test_topic_tools', 'test_roswtf', 'test_rostopic', 'test_rostime', 'test_rostest', 'test_rosservice', 'test_rospy', 'test_rosparam', 'test_rosnode', 'test_rosmsg', 'test_rosmaster', 'test_roslib_comm', 'test_roslaunch', 'test_rosgraph', 'test_roscpp_serialization_perf', 'test_roscpp_serialization', 'test_roscpp', 'test_rosbag', 'test_ros', 'test_crosspackage', 'perf_roscpp', 'roscore_migration_rules', 'std_srvs', 'std_msgs', 'rosgraph_msgs', 'rospy', 'roslisp', 'roscpp_traits', 'roscpp_serialization', 'roscpp']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .            
rosdep executing this script:
{{{
set -o errexit
#No packages to install
}}}
[ rosmake ] rosdep successfully installed all system dependencies                                                                               
[ rosmake ] Starting >>> tools/rospack                                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Finished <<< tools/rospack                                                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosemacs [ make ]                                                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosemacs  No Makefile in package rosemacs                                                                              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosboost_cfg [ make ]                                                                                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosboost_cfg  No Makefile in package rosboost_cfg                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbash [ make ]                                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbash  No Makefile in package rosbash                                                                                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                                              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                                                                                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> mk [ make ]                                                                                                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< mk  No Makefile in package mk                                                                                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib [PASS] [ 13.94 seconds ]                                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp [PASS] [ 14.36 seconds ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosdep [ make ]                                                                                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosdep  No Makefile in package rosdep                                                                                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmake [ make ]                                                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosunit [PASS] [ 1.69 seconds ]                                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscreate [ make ]                                                                                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosmake [PASS] [ 1.60 seconds ]                                                                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscreate [PASS] [ 2.01 seconds ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> test_rospack [ make ]                                                                                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosclean [PASS] [ 1.93 seconds ]                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> test_rosmake [ make ]                                                                                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< test_rosmake [PASS] [ 2.82 seconds ]                                                                                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> test_roslib [ make ]                                                                                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< test_rospack [PASS] [ 4.15 seconds ]                                                                                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> test_rosdep [ make ]                                                                                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< test_rosdep [PASS] [ 2.62 seconds ]                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> test_roscreate [ make ]                                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< test_roscreate [PASS] [ 1.79 seconds ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< test_roslib [PASS] [ 7.34 seconds ]                                                                                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph [PASS] [ 1.97 seconds ]                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                                                                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosmaster [PASS] [ 1.57 seconds ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                                                                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common [PASS] [ 1.66 seconds ]                                                                                     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                                                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_traits [PASS] [ 1.42 seconds ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs [PASS] [ 10.67 seconds ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostime [PASS] [ 3.25 seconds ]                                                                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                                                                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization [PASS] [ 2.41 seconds ]                                                                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs [PASS] [ 9.76 seconds ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy [PASS] [ 4.57 seconds ]                                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosnode [ make ]                                                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosnode [PASS] [ 7.86 seconds ]                                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] All 22 linesosconsole: 28.1 sec ] [ rosparam: 9.3 sec ]                                                  [ 2 Active 29/68 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package rosconsole
  [rosbuild] Including /Users/luca/ros/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /Users/luca/ros/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /Users/luca/ros/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  CMake Warning: The variable, 'CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE', specified manually, was not used during the generation.
  -- Build files have been written to: /Users/luca/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/build
  cd build && make -l2
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rosconsole.dir/src/rosconsole/rosconsole.o
  /Users/luca/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/src/rosconsole/rosconsole.cpp:684: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault: 11
  Please submit a full bug report,
  with preprocessed source if appropriate.
  See <URL:http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter> for instructions.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/rosconsole.dir/src/rosconsole/rosconsole.o] Error 1
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rosconsole.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rosconsole written to:ec ]                                                  [ 2 Active 29/68 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /Users/luca/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110722-113953/rosconsole/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole [FAIL] [ 28.12 seconds ]                                                                                    
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rosconsole. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosparam [PASS] [ 14.99 seconds ]                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 31 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] /Users/luca/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110722-113953                                                                             
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.16', 'rosinstall')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 489, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1214, in run_script
    exec script_code in namespace, namespace
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 556, in <module>
    
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 547, in rosinstall_main
    
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 504, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/luca/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

What can I do to solve the problem?

Thanks,
Luca

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10690/compiler-segmantion-fault-durint-ros-installation-on-osx-lion/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2011-07-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-08-22**:
@mrath asks "I uncommented the print function as well, however I don't get any output in rxconsole - could this be what the function does? I've only tried ROS the past few days, so I'm not sure if the problem is something else.."

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2011-08-08**:
So an update: commenting lines 569 and 576 out in file rosconsole.cpp will allow it to compile.  No idea why this happens.  I just used a binary search like approach to commenting in order to find those lines =p. I will try to figure it out, but input from others would be awesome.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2011-08-08**:
I am looking into this issue.  While it is definitely a compiler bug, I think it might be triggered by something in the code.  See: https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2011-07/msg00053.html.  igraph ran into a similar problem and they managed to work around it with code changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't found the problem with the compiler or ROS (specifically rosconsole), but I have found out what to comment out to work around the issue.  The print(...) function with an ellipsis in it (rosconsole.cpp) causes the issue.  I don't know why it does and I worked at it for quite a while, but then I realized that it doesn't seem to be being used (someone correct me if I am wrong), so I just commented it out.

You can see the fix here:

https://github.com/wjwwood/ros_comm/commit/71ccc123db3c7cd4c3343750ae0ef5803f7a828c

Or apply the patch yourself by downloading it from the ticket:

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3626

UPDATE:

There is a new patch that forces rosconsole to build with clang++ rather than llvm-g++ and it allows you to build cleanly without commenting out code.

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3626#comment:7

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2011-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2011-08-12**:
I don't know exactly, it looks like there are three print statements and they are only using one, and there fore you can safely comment the one in my patch out.  I didn't look very hard though, and that function might be needed, but I haven't run into problems yet.

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2011-08-11**:
@William  Fine! It works, now I can finally compile the base stacks. Does this patch exclude some important feature?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since it's a segfault in the compiler, it's unlikely to have much to do with ROS itself.

You didn't mention what compiler (and version) you are using. If there is a newer version of your compiler, I'd upgrade and see if that fixes it.

If not, you might want to try compiling with clang which is unlikely to have a bug in the same place.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-07-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2011-07-23**:
Thanks Asomervilee. I updated the compiler but nothing changed!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd recommend filing a bug at the suggested URL.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) on 2011-08-01**:
Was this ever filed, and where? any solutions so far?